# Shaping the values from a column into different columns

Tags: r

I'm working with a csv file where values are disposed like so :

```
   V1        V2

 1971       1.9

 1973       1.8 

 1974       1.7

 1975       1.95

 1976       2.05

 1977       1.9
```

I would like to flip the table on the side like so

```
1971 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977

1.9 1.8 1.7 1.95 2.05 1.9
```

I can use something like c(1970:2016) for the column names but I don't know how to distribute the values in colum 2. 
I have tried:

```
df<-data.frame(names=livestockIndex[1], values=livestockIndex[2])
```

as well as

```
df<-data.frame(names=as.matrix(livestockIndex[1]), values=livestockIndex[2])
```

The final goal is to produce a simple R histogram so maybe I don't need to change the shape of the table.
So here are my questions:
-Is there a way to input this data into an hist() function and make it work ?
-If not, how can I make this dataframe in the shape I need ?

*I'm only working with small parts of the dataset so will never have more than 1 row of data*

Comment: Have you tried transposing it `t()`? `as.numeric(df)`? `hist(df$V2)`?

Comment: you want a histogram of what exactly? V2? if what  you want is to plot  a column then all you have to do is pass the column to the hist function (e.g., `hist(my_Df$V2)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a histogram of the values in V2, you don't need to transpose anything.  You can just use `hist(mydata$V2)`.

A histogram won't show you how the values change over time, though, so if that's your goal, you can use a barplot instead: `barplot(V2 ~ V1, data = mydata)`. Line graphs are also good for showing how data changes over time: `plot(V2 ~ V1, data = mydata, type = "l")`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the easiest solution and it was clear.